# Firefox displaying form data in URL upon jquery AJAX post

Tags: javascript, firefox, asp.net-core

I have a login form which calls a jquery ajax request and posts the form data via an ASP.NET Web API endpoint.

So the process just checks username and password, and if it matches, redirect to home page. It works properly when I run from Chrome but I tested in FireFox and it's not redirecting but worst of all, it's putting the form data in the URL? Why is it doing that?

After posting, this is what the URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:50367/Account/Login?companycode=a&username=a&password=a
```

This does not happen in Chrome and I don't think I have anything in my code that would cause this.

The ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/Login",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(loginData)
})
.done((response) => {
    if (response.success) {
        window.location.href = response.returnUrl;
    }
})
.fail((error) => {      
});
```

What could be causing the form data to display in the URL for Firefox?

Comment: Is the default action of `<form>` submission prevented? Can you reproduce issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co? What is `response.returnUrl`?

Comment: have you tried changing 'method' to 'type'?

Comment: @rafon `type` is an alias for `method`. `method` is the preferred property to use since jQuery 1.9.0

Comment: @guest271314: It is indeed that. Not sure why its only happening in Firefox and not in Chrome though, but it was indeed that. I will mark as answer if you put in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default action of `<form>` submission.

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // do `$.ajax()` stuff
}
```